# How to show a special character (␣/"open box") in a checkbox label in Android 4.4?

Tags: android

I show a special character (␣) within a checkbox label in my Android app. I've just noticed that this symbol is missing on an Android 4.4 device. (In Android 5 and 7 it's visible.)

So far I have tried some workarounds I have found on stackoverflow:

- Replacing ␣ with an unicode string ("\u2423").
- Setting the text in Java (with setText()), not in strings.xml.
- Using fromHTML("xyz `&#9251;`").

Nothing of this works. Any other ideas?

Comment: Perhaps that glyph is not in the standard 4.x Ruboto font.

Comment: Maybe. Then I need another font or another symbol :-)

Comment: Yup. You could test with another font, one that you determine via your development machine has that glyph. If it shows up in a `TextView` using that `Typeface`, then your problem is Ruboto. If it does not show up, then for some reason none of your approaches for using that character are correct.